Given that $\dot x_t = a [(2p-1) y_t + 1-p - f(x_t)], \dot y_t = -b [(2p-1) y_t + 1-p - f(x_t)]$ prove that if $a \gg b$, then $f(x_t) \rightarrow p$.
I have a set of differential equations:
\begin{align*}
\dot x_t = a [(2p-1) y_t + 1-p - f(x_t)], \quad \dot y_t = -b [(2p-1) y_t + 1-p - f(x_t)]
\end{align*}
I know that $a, b > 0$, $ a \gg b$, $f(x) \in (0,1)$ is monotonically increasing, $p \in (1/2, 1)$, and that $y_0 = 1$. I want to show that $(f(x_t) - p)^2$ is small, for example something like $\exp(- at)$ but I think there should be some constant in addition to $a$ there, such as $p(1-p)$ or $f(x_0)(1-f(x_0)$. This intuitively makes sense. If $b \ll a$, then $y_t \approx y_0 = 1$. So the first differential equation simplifies to
$$\dot x_t = a (p - f(x_t))$$.
So at convergence with $\dot x_t \approx 0$, we have $f(x_t) \approx a$. How can I make this argument rigorous? I thought about finding a lower bound on $y_t$ showing that it is close to one, and then lower bounding $\dot x_t$ with that, but I am still not sure how to prove this.

This is linear non-homogeneous system of ordinary differential equations, which can be solved in closed form. Have you tried to work out the closed form of $x_t$ and then substitute $f(x_t)$?

@温泽海 I'm not sure how to solve this with closed form. I've tried using a symbolic solver but it is not able to find a solution

The system you provided definitely has a closed form solution. Use a fundamental solution and you will be able to solve such equations in closed form. See for example https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~scheel/teaching/8501-fall18/perko.pdf .
